# Add TFS Work Item Areas by XML import

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have a question, I am not sure whether it is possible or not.

I have to add few child of the `Work Item Area` in all the TFS projects by XML import.

For Work Item Types, We can do the same by importing the xml for all projects and it will update the work item type.

in the same way is it possible to import xml for `work item area` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool for TFS 2010 to export and import areas and iterations. See this [link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2007/07/07/copy-area-and-interation-structure-using-the-area-import-export-tool.aspx) for details. It works upon text files, but as the source code is available, you should be able to adjust it to your requirements and - if required - to a newer TFS version.

Instead of adjusting the tool to take XML files as an import, you could also convert your XML files to the format that the tool uses, e.g. by using XSLT.

For some samples on how to create areas and iterations programmatically, see these links:

- [Bulk update of TFS areas with ICommonStructureService](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jampick/archive/2009/06/06/bulk-update-of-tfs-areas-with-icommonstructureservice.aspx)
- [TFS API Part 10: Add Area/Iteration Programmatically](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/01/30/tfs-api-part-10-add-areaiteration-programmatically/)

Comment: +1 : That's a good solution. But is there any other way like same as what we do for **WIT** by importing XML ?

Comment: @SpiderCode: I don't know of an out of the box solution. The guy who created the tool is very experienced with TFS, so it is likely that there is no orb solution. Some years ago I've implemented the creation of areas in a tool with the TFS API (v2010). Was not too much effort. I try to find a link and update the answer.